# Saliency score using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Having a saliency map of an image (it has values between 0 and 1), my aim is to compute its globale score of saliency. I'm a bit confused, I don't know if I have to use the 'mean' or the 'median'. 
The problem of the mean is that low saliency values will pull down the global score of saliency. 
What kind of summons could I use for this question ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to compare if one image is more salient than another.  Is that right?

First please check if the saliency map is already normalized.  Many algorithms do this so that all images have the same mean (e.g., 0.5).

If there is no per image normalization, and you do not want to use the mean or median, perhaps you can use the mode.

Two sample outputs would be helpful. :)

Comment: The problem with the mod is that an imagine having lot of degrees of saliency equal to 0 will have a global score of saliecy equal to 0 !

Comment: Makes sense!  You can try the mode without 0's... I'm assuming the max is not useful.  Maybe you can also try quartiles.